# Python: How do I change this code so that I can doWork() once in every 60 seconds?

Tags: python, twisted

How do I change this code so that I can call doWork() once in every 60 seconds. Currently, it is looping in definitely and stops after 60 seconds. Want to do the exact reverse.

```
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
import twapi
timeout = 200.0 # Sixty seconds

def doWork():
    #do work here
    twapi.main('1')
    pass

l = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

Comment: What would you like to happen if `twapi.main` doesn't return in a minute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [oficial Twisted documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html)

```
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor

def runEverySecond():
    print "a second has passed"

l = task.LoopingCall(runEverySecond)
l.start(1.0) # call every second

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script to output current time once in a minute:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
from datetime import datetime as time
timeout = 60.0 # Sixty seconds

def doWork():
    #do work here
    print time.now().isoformat()

l = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

and it works just like that:

```
2012-05-20T19:24:44.388682
2012-05-20T19:25:44.389788
2012-05-20T19:26:44.389424
```

The only problem in your snippet I can see is that you ask the reactor to invoke your function once in every 200 seconds, not 60.